# Setting session variable from query result

Tags: php, mysql

I've been modifying a user authentication system and I'm having trouble setting a session for the admin. The `reguser` session is setting just fine, but I can't figure out why `admin` won't set.

A user with a `userlevel` of 9 is an admin. Yes, I know how to protect against SQL injection. I'm just trying to keep it as simple and easy to read for now. This probably won't get used for anything, I'm just getting some experience with PHP.

Hi everyone, thanks for your help! I got it to work. I had been staring at it for so long that my mind wasn't clear. Took a break from it yesterday, came back to it today and was able to figure it out in less than 5 minutes! You guys are awesome, I love stackoverflow!

```
function checklogin($email, $pass) {
        $server = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(udogoo, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
        $pass = md5($pass);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT userid from users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pass'");
        $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_rows == 1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['reguser'] = true;
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user_data['userid'];
        $userid = $user_data['userid'];
        $isadmin = mysql_query("SELECT userlevel FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid'");
        $isadmin2 =  mysql_fetch_array($isadmin);
        $isadmin3 = $isadmin2['userlevel'];
        if ($isadmin3 == "9"){
        $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
        return true;
    }
    }
        else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, to begin with, `$result` is a [resource returned from `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), so your inclusion of it in the `SELECT userlevel ...` is not actually searching by the `userid` as you think it is. It's probably searching for a `Resource ID #XX` or something.

Comment: Instead of using a plain `md5()` value for password, you might look into [`crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), using the `CRYPT_BLOWFISH` hash type with a salt value, which makes storing passwords much safer.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `return true;` if the user data exists. In fact, you only check or admin-ness if the user **doesn't** exist.

Remove that `return true;`, as it's not needed there. If you want, add `else return false;` after the check for the user's existence, and `return true;` right at the end.

Comment: Yeah, that's another problem. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is flawed as well, here:

```
function checklogin($email, $pass) 
{
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(test, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $pass = md5($pass);

    $sql = "SELECT `userid`,`userlevel` 
            FROM `users` 
            WHERE `email` = '$email' 
            AND `password` = '$pass' 
            LIMIT 1";  //I certainly hope you check email for injection before passing it here.  Also want the LIMIT 1 on there because you are only expecting a single return, and you should only get one since `email` should be unique since you're using it as a credential, and this will stop it from looking through all the rows for another match once it finds the one that matches.

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($numrows == 1) 
    {
        $_SESSION['reguser'] = true;
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $user_data['userid'];

        if($user_data['userlevel'] == 9)
        {
            $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['admin'] = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should work.  No good reason to do two queries when one will do just fine.  Returns true if user is logged in, false if user doesn't exist or credentials don't match.

Oops, small syntax error in the SQL statement, corrected.  Bigger syntax error also corrected.

And here's how you do the top part in PDO:

```
function checklogin($email, $pass) 
{
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'test';
    $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $dbname . ';host=' . $server;

    $conn = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);  //Establish connection   

    $pass = md5($pass);

    $sql = "SELECT `userid`,`userlevel` 
            FROM `users` 
            WHERE `email` = :email 
            AND `password` = :pass 
            LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR,128)  //First param gives the placeholder from the query, second is the variable to bind into that place holder, third gives data type, fourth is max length
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass',$pass,PDO::PARAM_STR,32)  //MD5s should always have a length of 32

    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();  //almost equivalent to mysql_query
    $user_data = $stmt->fetch();  //Grab the data

    if(is_array($user_data) && count($user_data) == 2)  //Check that returned info is an array and that we have both `userid` and `userlevel`
    {
        //Continue onwards
```

Comment: You could demonstrate how to escape the email address (although the OP does mention escaping in the email). Note, escaping is just a good practice, not necessarily a security practice.

Comment: Really, since it's an email, just checking it for valid email format would be enough of an escapement on it.  Can't think of any SQL injections you can fit in the format xxx@xxx.xxx or xxx@xxx.xx.xx.  Me, I just make sure my inputs fit what they're supposed to and use PDO with prepared statements and bound parameters and don't worry too much about it anymore.

Comment: That's some unusual advice. As the example and your answer do not use PDO, escaping is a matter of fact requirement. Validation notwithstanding, inputs in queries should be escaped in most cases.

Comment: I just realized something: You're missing `FROM users` in the query.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Fixed `FROM users`.  He's not using PDO so I didn't do it in PDO, so I noted it should be escaped.  PDO escapes inputs and checks their data type for validity when using prepared statements and bound parameters.  If his question was "how do you escape mysql_query query inputs" then I would have gone into how to escape it.

Comment: Yes, in a comment that's about five scrolls to the right. You did a good job of demonstrating a single query, why are you so ambivalent about demonstrating using `mysql_real_escape_string()` in practice?

Comment: Because it might already be escaped before being passed to the function, in which case escaping it again is a bad idea.

Comment: Eh, if it is, I'd say *that's* a bad idea (early escaping, that is).

Comment: I upvoted your answer (and pimped it) a while back. Happy? I thought it was a good and thoughtful approach. In the intermediate, I thought it possibly lacking in areas that could be easily improved. I'm not *happy*, I just think it's a better answer. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$userid = $user_data['user_id'];
$isadmin = mysql_query("SELECT userlevel FROM users WHERE userid = $userid");

$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$userlevel = $user_data['userlevel'];

if($userlevel == '9')
{
  $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
}
```

so, your complete code look like this::

```
<?php
function checklogin($email, $pass) 
{
        $server = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or     die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(test, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
        $pass = md5($pass);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT userid from users WHERE email = '$email'  AND password = '$pass'");
        $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($numrows == 1) 
        {
            $_SESSION['reguser'] = true;
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user_data['userid'];

            //MY ANSWER START HERE
            $userid = $_SESSION['userid']; 
            $isadmin = mysql_query("SELECT userlevel FROM users WHERE userid = $userid");

            $user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $userlevel = $user_data['userlevel'];

            if($userlevel == '9')
            {
              $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
            }
            //END HERE 

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this before and it didn't work. The strange part is it's nearly identical to how the "reguser" session is set.

Comment: It's possible the `user_id` is an alphanumeric field, so it might need to be `'$userid'`. But this does appear to deal with the obvious mistake of using `$result` to search on.

Comment: Just an aside, but if `$_SESSION['userid']` is set correctly, you could use it instead of a function-scoped variable...

Comment: Note @Kolink's answer, though, which discusses the fact that the function short-circuits before getting to your for valid users. That `return TRUE` needs to come out too.

Comment: @JaredFarrish what do you mean by instead of a "function-scoped variable". Sorry, I never had any formal programming lessons so I don't know a lot of the terminology. I probably know what you mean, just not the definition of it.

Comment: @user1104854 - Just that a local (in this case function-scoped) variable is unnecessary if the `$_SESSION` variable is already set. Note, Phoenix's answer also provides a more compact way of handling the request. I might also suggest a global `$dbconn` variable or a singleton, so you don't have to pepper your code with `mysql_connect()` statements.

Comment: @Jared Farrish could also pass a dbh by reference to functions from one master dbh.

Comment: @user1104854: please refer to Phoenix's answer, simple, compact and i'm 100% sure its work.

Comment: @Phoenix - Yes, dependency injection is another approach.

Comment: @user1104854 Variables are limited in scope to the area in which they are assigned.  A variable set inside a function is not accessible outside the function and is destroyed when the function ends, unless the variable is a global variable like the superglobal $_SESSION.  There's also namespace variable scoping now.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php